# Adblock rule to block g+ / twitter / etc.

Tags: networking, firewall, firefox, adblock

Looks like this rule works to blocking facebook domain, when not visiting the facebook domain (ex.: "like/share" etc. buttons on other pages then facebook):

```
! don't allow facebook outside facebook..
||facebook.com$domain=~www.facebook.com
||facebook.net$domain=~www.facebook.com
||fbcdn.net$domain=~www.facebook.com
facebook.com###appsNav
facebook.com###pagesNav
facebook.com###groupsNav
facebook.com###pagelet_friends_online
facebook.com###pagelet_bookmark_nav
facebook.com###pagelet_rhc_footer
```

But how can I block completely twitter / g+ / etc sites with adblock rules? (Is this really effective, or it only makes me not to see the fcb buttons/etc.)?

Comment: Shouldn't this question be on [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/) instead of here?  I don't see anything *nix specific.

Comment: @depquid It doesn't matter: [being cross-platform does not disqualify](http://unix.stackexchange.com/faq).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try [Ghostery](http://www.ghostery.com/) to see if it doesn't do what you want.  It's not a set of adblock  rules, but rather an entire plugin devoted to webbugs, profiling, etc.